# getting undefined is not an object error (evaluating 'dashboardModel.categories.map')

Tags: react-native

While trying to execute this react native app I'm having troubles as it says that the object is undefined. All the imports are done correctly and the app seems to work fine except for this point.

I'm getting this object is undefined error in the `dashboardModel.categories.map` line. The exact error is this one:

[image]

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { getString } = useLocalization();
  const { colors, sizes } = useTheme();
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();
  const [selectedCategoryIndex, setSelectedCategoryIndex] = useState(0);
  const [dashboardModel, setDashboardModel] = useState<DashboardModel>({
    categories: [],
    highlightedNews: [],
    topCategories: [],
    news: [],
    stories: [],
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const fetchDashboardItems = () => {
    DashboardService.getDashboardItems()
      .then((res) => {
        setDashboardModel(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => alert(err.message));
  };

  useEffect(() => fetchDashboardItems(), []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: "always" }}>
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => fetchDashboardItems()}
          />
        }
      >
        {/* toolbar */}
        <HomeHeaderView />

        <Divider mh16 style={{ marginTop: 12 }} />

        {/* Stories */}
        <FlatList<StoryModel>
          data={dashboardModel.stories}
          horizontal
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Separator horizontal width={8} />}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListDefaultContainerStyle}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => `storyItemKey${index}`}
          renderItem={({ index, item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate(NavigationNames.StoryPreviewScreen, {
                  stories: [...dashboardModel.stories],
                  selectedIndex: index,
                })
              }
            >
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: getImageUrl(item.thumbnailImageName),
                }}
                style={[
                  styles.storiesItemImage,
                  {
                    borderColor: item.relatedNews.category.color,
                  },
                ]}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />

        <Divider mh16 />

        {/* Highlighted News */}
        <HomeHighlightedNewsView
          news={dashboardModel.highlightedNews}
          onClickItem={(news) =>
            navigation.push(NavigationNames.NewsDetailScreen, {
              model: { ...news },
            })
          }
        />

        {/* Categories */}
        <SectionHeader title={getString("top_categories")} mTop={16} />

        <FlatList
          data={dashboardModel.topCategories}
          horizontal
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Separator horizontal width={12} />}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListDefaultContainerStyle}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => `topCategoryItemKey${index}`}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <HomeCategoriesItemView
              item={item}
              onSelectedCategory={(category: CategoryModel) => {
                navigation.navigate(NavigationNames.SearchTab, {
                  screen: NavigationNames.SearchScreen,
                  params: { category: { ...category } },
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        />

        {/* Latest News */}
        <SectionHeader title={getString("latest_news")} mTop={16} />

        <ScrollableTabBarLayout
          items={[
            { title: getString("today_upper"), color: colors.primaryColor },
            ...dashboardModel.categories.map((item) => {
              return { title: item.name, color: item.color };
            }),
          ]}
          selectedIndex={selectedCategoryIndex}
          onChangeSelected={setSelectedCategoryIndex}
        />

        <FlatList<NewsModel>
          data={
            selectedCategoryIndex === 0
              ? dashboardModel.news.slice(0, 5)
              : dashboardModel.news.filter(
                (item) =>
                  item.category.name ===
                  dashboardModel.categories[selectedCategoryIndex - 1].name
              )
          }
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Separator />}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListDefaultContainerStyle}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => `newsItemKey${index}`}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.push(NavigationNames.NewsDetailScreen, {
                  model: { ...item },
                })
              }
            >
              <NewsListItemWideView item={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  storiesItemImage: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 80,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
  },
  flatListDefaultContainerStyle: { paddingHorizontal: 16, paddingVertical: 12 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hey maybe you don't have to give the spread operator on your map so it would be

```
dashboardModel.map.categories
```

instead of

```
...dashboardModel.map.categories
```